# Flutter and dart Plugins not installed

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I already installed the Flutter and Dart Plugins in my Android Studio 4.1.0, but whenever I try to run `flutter doctor` in the command prompt, it will have an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgH2Z.png).

[image]

I tried uninstalling flutter and dart then installing them again but the same error.

The error occurs on Windows.

Comment: What is your operating system? Windows, osx, linux please share more information.

It might be link error also, open android studio>preferences>language & frameworks then select dart & flutter section, if fields are empty click on them and select location of SDK paths

Comment: make sure from android plugin marketplace that the plugins are installed

Comment: Hello @FaiiziiAwan I already did install Flutter and Dart in the marketplace but nothing still works

Comment: did you update the android studio from old version to 4.1.0 ? or you have installed the 4.1.0 directly

Comment: @FaiiziiAwan I downloaded the latest version. I tried doing everything but it won't work

Answer (score 3):

The same thing happens quite frequently to me because I'm switching flutter channels often.
Try `flutter channel (master|beta|stable)`, `flutter upgrade`, `flutter doctor -v` and see if the issue persists. Anyway, it's not a real problem if everything works fine for your development work.

Comment: Hi! I already did it but still the error is there

Answer (score 1):

I find the reason behind it, why is `flutter doctor` command giving the issue/error/warning?

[image]

Android studio 4.1 has changed the directory of installed plugins. you can find the new directory at

> C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins

The issue is already reported on Github and one of the contributor of flutter replied as

> Failing to detect the plugins will not affect Flutter development at
> all. The Flutter CLI tool does not touch the plugins, only your editor
> does. Because of this, we plan to deprecate the plugin validators

Comment: Hello. Thank you for this!! Should I put this in my Environment Variable?

Comment: If you want to use flutter CLI, yes you should. You can ignore this warning/error/issue

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this problem.

What I did is just switch the channel to dev

```
flutter channel dev
```

then

```
flutter upgrade
```